# Facebook Page Comments Using Graph API & Stream Filter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have my site working using the Facebook Comments Plugin as you can see here http://www.amanzitravel.com/namibia-wildlife-sanctuary

I am trying to use the Graph API to retrieve the comments so they are on the page in a form that is beneficial for SEO (as outlined here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/).

Ideally I want to see not only all comments, but replies to comments. According to the API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/comments) using `filter=stream` should do the trick.

However when I do that I only get the two most recent comments e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.amanzitravel.com/namibia-wildlife-sanctuary&filter=stream as opposed to the default https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.amanzitravel.com/namibia-wildlife-sanctuary where I get all the top level comments but none of the replies.

EDIT: Further to this, it appears to update itself some time later, but when another reply is added it goes back to displaying a subset of all the comments for a period of time. Its unfortunate because it means I can't rely on this to be accurate.

Is there anyway I can make this work properly?